# How to distinct the values inside json in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @a int = 752 , @b nvarchar(max) = '[4,4]'
```

I want to result which give me distinct records inside b

```
 a    b
752  [4]
```

The b could be anything so the logic would be generic

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you already have logic to parse @b into array elements? Have you applied `DISTINCT` to the intermediate result? Are you now looking for a way to construct a JSON array from those distinct values? You say "b could be anything". Please clarify. Is @b always a JSON array at the top level or could it be any valid JSON or even any arbitrary text? Are the inner elements always integers or any valid JSON element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support `JSON_AGG`, so you need to hack it with `STRING_AGG`.

```sql
DECLARE @a int = 752 , @b nvarchar(max) = '[4,4]';

SELECT
  @a AS a,
  (
    SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(value, ',') + ']'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT value
        FROM OPENJSON(@b) AS j
    ) j
  ) AS b;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/_8LZCiAZ)